# Add loop results

Tags: java, loops

I'm new to Java and I have a simple problem to solve, but I don't actually know how to finish it.

I have a loop which looks like this:

```
    double i = 0.5 , y , w, p;
    for (double x = 0 ; x <= 2; x=x+i)
    {
     y = Math.pow(x, 2);
     w = 4 - y;
     p = w * i;
    }
```

So it makes 5 calculations. It's obviously not very difficult, but I don't know how to make it add the results, so I could make it display only the outcome.

Comment: what 5 calculations does it make?

Comment: Your `x=x+i` is already adding the values of `i` so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Side note: `x = x + i` is normally written `x += i`.

Comment: Also `x * x` is not only shorter than `Math.pow(x, 2)` but much, much faster.

Comment: I want to sum up the 'p = w * i' results.

Comment: And since you know how to sum up values (you are doing it already) what is stopping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a variable to hold the total. For example;

```
double sum;
double i = 0.5 , y , w, p;
for (double x = 0 ; x <= 2; x=x+i)
{
 y = Math.pow(x, 2);
 w = 4 - y;
 p = w * i;
 sum += p;
}
```

Notice how I used **sum += p**. This is shorthand for *sum = sum + p*. You should do the same with **x=x+i**. Also you should change **y = Math.pow(x, 2)** to **y = x*x**. This is faster than using Math.pow.

After all these changes the final code would end up being;

```
double sum;
double i = 0.5 , y , w, p;
for (double x = 0 ; x <= 2; x += i)
{
 y = x * x;
 w = 4 - y;
 p = w * i;
 sum += p;
}
```

**Side note:**

You could also do **p += w * i**, but in my opinion creating a variable to hold the sum is much cleaner.

Comment: It would be a good habit to initialize variables, even if primitives get a default value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to add the result of each iteration, in which case the following would suffice:

```
double i = 0.5 , y , w, p = 0;
for (double x = 0 ; x <= 2; x=x+i)
{
    y = Math.pow(x, 2);
    w = 4 - y;
    p += w * i;
}
System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Well, I thought about that. If I put it in the loop, the results are: 2.0,
1.875,
1.5,
0.875,
0.0. But your method doesn't work.

Comment: Should you initialize `p` with 0 value in the declaration?

Comment: @user2900052 `it doesn't work` is one of the most common and most uninformative statements on StackOverflow.  Tell us what does work.

Comment: If your error was `variable p might not have been initialized` make sure to assign `p` to `0` as @peeskillet said (I've also edited the answer). If not, then there's something wrong with your algorithm or with what results you're expecting out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the answer

create a `double sumP` and everytime `p` is given a value, add `p` to `sumP`

Make sure `sumP` is placed before your loop.

After loop, print `sumP`

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a floating point is dangerous due to representation error. You are better off iterating over an int value as you know how many iterations you will get.

```
double f = 0.5, p = 0.0;
for(int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
   double x = j * f;
   p += f * (4 - x * x);
}

System.out.println(p);
```

I suggest you avoid using `i` for doubles as it is usually used for loops.

---

EDIT consider

```
for (double d = 0; d <= 2; d += 0.1)
    System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
1.2
1.3
1.4000000000000001
1.5000000000000002
1.6000000000000003
1.7000000000000004
1.8000000000000005
1.9000000000000006
```

Note: there is NO 2.0 loop.

where as

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    double d = i / 10.0;
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

prints

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```

Comment: It also has to work for iterations 0.1 and 0.01. This is why my code looks that way.

Comment: @user2900052 It "work"s because the last expression is 0 so it doesn't matter if it is evaluated or not. In another loop, it wouldn't work.